# Alternative to bananas in Europe

Tags: food, carbon-footprint

If you buy bananas in Europe, they usually come with a high CO<sub>2</sub> level, since they are mostly produced overseas.

**Is there a fruit produced in Europe which comes quite close to bananas in terms of energy supply, digestibility, and shelf life?**

Right now, bananas are to me the only fruit which delivers enough energy before or during sports activities. I have tried dry figs but have problems to digest them.

Comment: You could grow your own banana tree. But why do you assume that produce from overseas has a great CO2 level? Compared to what?

Comment: Compared to locally (from Europe) produced fruit. I cannot accept growing your own banana tree as an answer

Comment: Not really an answer, but suggest reading the book 'How bad are bananas' by Mike Berners-Lee. This attempts to estimate the carbon footprint of various foods and activities. Turns out bananas aren't really that bad compared to, for example, the european apples in the shops now (April) which have been refrigerated since autumn. Transport is only part of the problem - refrigeration and production are also important carbon sources.

Comment: What's special about bananas ? I suspect from cycling that they're a good mix of starch and sugar, in their own sustainable wrapper (not as quickly  biodegradable as you'd think BTW).

Comment: They are quite unique in terms of quick energy supply. No wonder that for extreme endurance sports such as skyrunning, cycling, triathlon they are the number one.

Answer (score 1):

Europe produces bananas. The come from Spain, in particular The Canary Islands and the fruit is called [Platanos](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pl%C3%A1tanos_de_Canarias.JPG) (which is Banana in Spanish).

You can identify them because they use this [stiker](https://colnect.com/en/fruit_stickers/fruit_sticker/7486-Platano_de_Canarias-Spain)

Answer (score -2):

Sustainability is all about going local. Instead of trying to find a fruit similar to a banana you might as well look around you and observe what fruits are available around you that are not imported, and I am sure that you will find plenty of them.